# How many pairings are needed to verify beta term in GGPR13 zk-snark? Pinocchio paper says 3 but I count 4

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings, snarks

The [Pinocchio](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf) paper contains a description of the GGPR protocol (Protocol 1), and states that verification requires "8 pairings for the $\alpha$ terms, and 3 for the $\beta$ term". However I can't figure out how to verify the $\beta$ term with 3 pairings, it seems to require 4.

For context, the proof is given as:

$$
( g^{v_{mid}}, g^w, g^y, g^h, g^{\alpha v_{mid}}, g^{\alpha w}, g^{\alpha y}, g^{\alpha h}, g^{\beta_v v_{mid} + \beta_w w + \beta_y y} )
$$

Where $v_{mid}, w, y, h$ are polynomials evaluated at point $s$.

The verifier key is given as

$$
(g^1, g^\alpha, g^\gamma, g^{\beta_v \gamma}, g^{\beta_w \gamma}, g^{\beta_y \gamma}, ... )  
$$

For bilinear map $e$, the 8 pairings for the $\alpha$ terms are clear, in the form of 4 pairs like $e(g^w, g^\alpha) = e(g^{\alpha w}, g)$, with one pair for each of $v_{mid}, w, y, h$. For the $\beta$ term I would expect verification to occur using the following 4 pairings:

$$
e(g^{\beta_v v_{mid} + \beta_w w + \beta_y y}, g^{\gamma}) = e(g^{v_{mid}}, g^{\beta_v \gamma})e(g^{w}, g^{\beta_w \gamma})e(g^{y}, g^{\beta_y \gamma})
$$

Am I missing something that would allow this $\beta$ term to be verified in only 3 pairings?

For additional context, the [GGPR](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/215.pdf) paper itself doesn't even mention the use of pairings here, it instead says (page 51):

"Using the quadratic root detection, V confirms that ... $\gamma Z - (\beta_v \gamma)v_{mid} - (\beta_w \gamma)w - (\beta_y \gamma)y = 0$"

where $Z = \beta_v v_{mid} + \beta_w w + \beta_y y$

Thanks!